# Copied project "product ID" fault in app catalogue

Tags: sharepoint-online, json, gulp

I have an web part that I have copiedto two examples and modified the other one.

However, when I try to upload them both to an app catalogue I get an error (the same product ID exists for the second app). I have tried to manually change the product ID in the "package-solution" JSON in the config map, without results. I also have tried to make a new scaffolding project and manually replace some files, but it still complains when I try the project with "gulp serve".

How is it the easiest way to change a product ID for a project? And which files is it defined so I can replace them with a new solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sample Demo to duplicate a existing solution.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]